# Apache <LocationMatch> Directive

Tags: apache-2.2

Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all

doesn't work! I still can access http://example.com/?page=test

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, the LocationMatch directive does not match query parameters.  Your URL is "http://example.com/", and that is what you can match.

You can use `mod_rewrite` to match the query string; the following is from [the mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
Note: Query String

The Pattern will not be matched against the query string. Instead, 
you must use a RewriteCond with the %{QUERY_STRING} variable.
```